# Quais são as melhorias que a implementação do Spread Operator trará para o javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estou dando uma olhada nas new features do  `EcmaScript6` e vi que foi implementado o `Spread Operator`.

Ele parece bem semelhante ao `variadic function` do PHP (que também usa `Spread Operator`).

Aqui tenho um exemplo de como será a diferença entre as codificações atuais e `Ecmascript6`:

Antes:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Depois:

```
var max = Math.max(...[1, 2, 3]);
```

E também na declaração das funções:

Antes:

```
 function myFunc(name) {      
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    // faça o restante
 }
```

Depois:

```
  function myFunc(name, ...args)
  {
     // faça o restante
  }
```

No PHP, a implementação de `variadic function` trouxe como melhorias algumas coisas:

- Não ter que usar `call_user_func_array`
- Não ter que usar `func_get_args`.

Gostaria de saber que, no javascript, o que será impactante com essa implementação do `Spread Operadators`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A própria pergunta já traz duas dessas melhorias, certo? Bom, quase. Na verdade, o segundo exemplo é bem diferente do primeiro.

O primeiro exemplo mostra o que se costuma chamar de *spread operator* (*): ele vem à esquerda de uma lista (um [*Iterable*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-iterable-interface), geralmente uma array) e espalha ou "desdobra" seu conteúdo em variáveis distintas. No seu exemplo, os itens da lista são distribuídos como argumentos no momento da chamada da função:

```
var max = Math.max(...[1, 2, 3]);  // equivale a Math.max(1, 2, 3)
```

Em ES5, como você notou, isso só é possível com `apply`, que é bem menos legível.

O segundo exemplo tem a semântica oposta: na lista de parâmetros de uma função, o `...` não distribui uma lista em valores, e sim coleta os valores em uma lista:

```
function myFunc(name, ...args) { } // args coleta todos os argumentos passados depois de name
```

Isso costuma ser chamado de *rest parameters*, ou parâmetros restantes. Na assinatura da função, eles só podem aparecer no final. Independente do nome, claramente é uma melhoria de sintaxe, pois elimina a necessidade do `slice.call(arguments, n)` dentro da função, o que seria necessário em ES5.

Voltando ao *spread operator*, ele tem outros usos além do que você mostrou no primeiro exemplo. Em arrays literais, ele permite concatenar e interpolar arrays:

```
let umaArray = [3, 4];
let outraArray = [6, 7];
let combo = [1, 2, ...umaArray, 5, ...outraArray];
// combo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Ele também pode ser utilizado do lado esquerdo de uma operação de desestruturação ([*destructuring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), recurso bem interessante, parecido um pouco com o `list` do PHP, mas mais poderoso):

```
[a, ...outros] = [1,2,3,4];
// a = 1
// outros = [2, 3, 4]
```

Por fim, ele ainda permite fazer algo que exigia um certo malabarismo em ES5, uma espécie de `apply` combinado com `new`:

```
new Date(...[2015,7, 31]);
```

O equivalente em ES5 era essa "beleza" aqui:

```
new (Date.bind.apply(Date, [null, 2015, 7, 31]));
```

## Referências

- [MDN: Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- [MDN: Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [MDN: Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [ES6 Spread and Butter in Depth](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-spread-and-butter-in-depth)
- [ECMA-262 - Especificação](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html)

---

(*) Na especificação isso nem é listado como um operador; a gramática da linguagem trata o `...` literalmente, e distingue a semântica do spread e do rest conforme o contexto.

Comment: Gostei, bonita explicação :D

Comment: A parte que achei mais interessante é a do "combo". Não tinha pensando nesse uso.