# Para que serve o operador '...' no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Vi alguns usos do `...` porém não sei ao certo o que o mesmo faz. Exemplo:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [4, 5, ...a];
```

Como chama-se esse operador e como funciona?

Comment: Ele é chamado de Spread. Tem mais informações aqui: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais são as melhorias que a implementação do Spread Operator trará para o javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111497)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ele transforma um objeto que é uma coleção de dados em uma lista de dados. O nome dele é *spread* ([documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)).

Pode ser usado para transformar um *array* em argumentos de entrada de uma função, em preenchimento de outro *array*, ou na criação de um objeto baseado em um *array*.

Não se esquecendo que uma *string* não deixa de ser um *array*.

No seu exemplo `b` terá como resultado `4, 5, 1, 2, 3`.

Bem grosso modo é como ele copiasse aquela lista de elementos e colasse em outro lugar que espera uma lista. Não é assim que funciona porque a coleção de dados não precisa ter sido criada como um literal, mas entenda assim só para visualizar melhor o que está ocorrendo.

Seria mais ou menos o mesmo que:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [4, 5];
b = b.concat(a);
console.log(b);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Concat.js).