# Utilização de ... em Arrays (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber para que serve os "..." antes de um Array em Javascript.

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Duplicata de [Para que serve o operador '…' no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266612/5878)

Comment: Obg pela ajuda.