# Como fazer uma função com quantidade de parâmetros 'infinita'?

Tags: javascript

Como faço uma função em JavaScript que pode receber uma quantidade *infinita* de parâmetros?

Quando me refiro a *infinita*, tenho ciência que existe um limite, mas quero fazer uma função onde a pessoa possa passar quantos parâmetros ela quiser: um, dois, cinco, dez, e que faça a mesma coisa para cada parâmetro passado para ela.

Um exemplo simples seria algo como:

```
function multiplicar(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
  return n1*n2*n3*n4;
}
```

Só que ao invés de aceitar 4 parâmetros, aceite uma quantidade de 2 a quantos a pessoa colocar (dado o limite suportado pela linguagem)

Como uma pergunta bônus, caso saibam, qual seria o limite de parâmetros que uma função pode receber em JavaScript?

Comment: Relacionada: [Para que serve o operador '…' no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266612/5878)

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais são as melhorias que a implementação do Spread Operator trará para o javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111497/5878)

Comment: Relacionada: [Existe um padrão de projeto ou recomendação que define a quantidade ideal de parâmetros que uma função deve ter?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315355/5878)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilize os 3 pontos antes de um parâmetro. Ele serve para que você utilize `n` parâmetros.

Seu nome é Spread e pode ser visto mais sobre na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

> `n` será um array dentro da função multiplicar

```js
function multiplicar(...n) {
  let valor = n.reduce(function (valorAcumulado , valorAtual) { 
    return valorAcumulado *= valorAtual;
  }, 1)
  console.log(valor);
}

multiplicar(2,3,4);
```

Recomendo a leitura: [Para que serve o operador '…' no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266612/para-que-serve-o-operador-no-javascript)

Comment: Entendi, obrigado. Se é que posso perguntar isso aqui, existe uma forma de eu me referir a um parametro específico entre a quantidade indefinida de parametros? Pelo que eu entendi eu pegaria o index de n?

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo `n` será um array. Consegue entender?

Comment: Sim, eu entendi isso, estava realmente confirmando se meu raciocínio estava correto (se eu poderia usar n[3] para me referir ao quarto parametro passado na função, por exemplo)

Novamente obrigado.

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo sim, pode usar do jeito que se referiu!