# Duvida em função setState

Tags: javascript, react

Gostaria de saber porque usar e o funcionando quando utilizamos setState, em alguns momentos eu vejo exemplos como este abaixo:

```
    this.setState({
      edit: {
        ...this.state.edit
      }
    });
```

Por que ele utiliza os três pontos (...) antes de this.state.edit, o que isso faz?

Comment: [**Quais são as melhorias que a implementação do Spread Operator trará para o javascript?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111497)

Comment: [**Documentação MDN - Spread operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)