# O que significa os três pontinhos ... antes de document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

No código a seguir o que significa os três pontinhos que antecedem `document.querySelectorAll`

```
const [marcas, valor] = [...document.querySelectorAll('input.classNew')];

marcas.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    //codigo
}
```

> Fiz inúmeras buscas no site e no Google sem obter exito.

Obs: sei que se retirar um ou mais pontinho dá erro no script

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais são as melhorias que a implementação do Spread Operator trará para o javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111497/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, valeu!!!!

Comment: Eu positivei a pergunta e negativei as duas respostas, acredito que votar como duplicata é a melhor ação nessa "boa" pergunta

Comment: A principal vantagem e poder copiar o array invés de passar a referencia.

Comment: @MarceloBoni, após o @ AndersonCarlosWoss ter me indicado os links eu ia remover a pergunta mas as respostas dadas não me deixam remover.

Comment: @MarceloBoni é legal você ler "quando negativar uma resposta" que diz claramente que você deve negativar apenas quando a resposta está perigosamente errada. Atitudes como  a que foi tomada nesse caso desmotivam a responder. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) você confere uma explicação de quando você deve votar contra.

Comment: @Sorack a resposta não está errada, mas acabam tirando o mérito das outras respostas (posso estar enganado e pode até ser exagero), acredito que vincular as outras respostas a está pergunta e fecha-la como duplicata, talvez possa vir a ser o melhor nesse caso (mais uma vez, pode ser um exagero da minha parte)

Comment: @MarceloBoni sim, é exagero e o modo errado de usar o downvote, como você pode ler no que eu linkei. Vou ressaltar aqui "Use os votos contra quando encontrar uma publicação destacadamente negligente e malfeita ou uma resposta que esteja claramente, e talvez perigosamente, incorreta.". E também "Os votos contra devem ser reservados para casos extremos".

Comment: Downvote é coisa de super gênio preguiçoso. Sabe pra caramba, acha sua pergunta/resposta incorreta mas NÂO apresenta argumentos. No meu caso, dessa pergunta, ele deve ter achado que eu tinha obrigação de saber a respeito desse operador ou talvez não tenha visto minha dificuldade `Fiz inúmeras buscas no site e no Google sem obter exito.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Essa é uma sintaxe do `ES6` chamada `operador spread`.

> [`Operador Spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
>
> O operador spread permite uma expressão ser expandida em locais onde múltiplos argumentos (por chamadas de função) ou múltiplos elementos (por array literais) são esperados.

Basicamente no seu caso serve para definir que os elementos contidos no `array` serão utilizados 1 a 1 dentro de outro array, atribuindo o primeiro valor à variável `marcas` e o seguindo a variável `valor`.

Comment: `O basicamente no seu caso .... utilizados 1 a 1 dentro de outro array` foi decisivo para que eu entendesse claramente o significado do `Operador Spread`

Answer (score 0):

É o operador Spread do Javascript.
Você expande uma expressão em que há múltiplos argumentos, por exemplo:

```
function sum(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}

let myArray = [1, 2];
console.log(sum(...myArray)); //3

let spreadInArray = [3, 4, ... myArray];
console.log(spreadInArray); //[ 3, 4, 1, 2 ]
```