# O que a Rest syntax retorna exatamente, apenas os elementos ou algum objeto especial?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Fazendo alguns exercícios, percebi que é possível usar a função map em um rest que aparentemente só retorna elementos puros. também percebi que não é possível aplicar um typeof e nem forEach.

Alguém poderia explicar o motivo disso? gostaria de saber:

- o que exatamente o Rest retorna
- por que é possível aplicar um map, mas não um forEach
- por que que quando no console, aparentemente o rest só retorna elementos "puros"

código de exemplo:

```js
const arr = ["ana", "carlos", "rafael"]

console.log(...arr) // <- retorna os elementos apenas, sem array

console.log(...arr.map(e => e.toUpperCase())) // <- é possível usar map, como se fosse uma array

console.log(...arr.forEach(e => e.toUpperCase())) // <- não é possivel usar forEach...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, não tem *rest parameters* aí, e sim o *spread operator*. Para entender melhor a diferença, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111497/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-melhorias-que-a-implementa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-spread-operator-trar%c3%a1-para-o-javas/111683#111683). O que ele faz é extrair os valores da array, e passar adiante.

Acho que a melhor maneira de explicar o que está acontecendo é simplificando o que cada um dos seus exemplos está realmente passando para o `console.log`.

## Exemplo 1

```
console.log("ana", "carlos", "rafael")
```

Esse é o caso mais simples: os valores são desestruturados do array pelo spread operator e passados como argumentos distintos ao `console.log`.

## Exemplo 2

```
console.log("ANA", "CARLOS", "RAFAEL")
```

No fundo é quase igual ao primeiro, mas o que é desestruturado é a nova array retornada pelo `map` – o que já indica o que dá errado no exemplo seguinte. O ponto importante aqui é que o map executa primeiro, sobre a array, e depois o spread opera sobre o retorno do map (que é uma nova array).

## Exemplo 3

```
console.log(...undefined)
```

É isso mesmo, teste isso no seu console e vai ver que o erro é exatamente o mesmo que ocorre com o seu `forEach`. O que está chegando para o spread operator é o retorno do `forEach`. E esse método percorre a array e retorna `undefined`. Como `undefined` não é uma coleção, não pode ser operando do spread, por isso o erro.

Comment: hmm obrigado amigo, eu estava quebrando a cabeça com isso. Mas ainda me resta uma dúvida... estão quer dizer que o operador spread, mesmo localizado na frente dos elementos, ele só retorna algo depois do retorno dos elementos na frente dele à ele?

Comment: Basicamente sim. Ele não é um operador de verdade (é meio complicado explicar), mas pode considerar que ele executa por último.