# Encontrar a palavra mais longa usando .sort()

Tags: javascript, funções

Como fazer uma função para encontrar a palavra mais longa entre um conjunto de palavras porém só encontro códigos que ajudam a encontrar a palavra mais longa dentro de uma frase

Segue o código que fiz

```
function findLongestWord(str){
  return str.split(" ").sort(function(a, b){return b.length - a.length})[0];
  
  var words = str.split(" ");
  var longest = "";
  
  for (var word of words) {
    if (word.length > longest.length) longest = word;
  }
  return longest.length
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The", "quick", "brown"));
```

Comment: Da maneira que implementou está passando 3 parâmetros para a função. Como falou em conjunto entendo que gostaria de passar, um array de palavras, como parâmetro da função. É isso?

Comment: Sim, gostaria de passar um array com palavras como deixei de exemplo no console.log ("the", "quick", "brown") e daí uma função que retorne "brown" somente

Comment: Eu _pessoalmente_ acho que não é uma ideia semanticamente correta utilizar função com aridade variada nesse tipo de situação (vários argumentos). Julgo ser mais ideal passar um único array no primeiro (e único) argumento. Acabaria facilitando também na aplicação de valores que já estão no formato de array, sem precisar de usar _spread_ ou `apply` na invocação...

Answer (score 3):

Do jeito que você escreveu, pode usar o [parâmetro Rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) para colocar todos os argumentos (onde `args` é um array) da funcão e fazer o `sort` da mesma forma que você fez:

```js
function findLongestWord(...args){
  return 'A maior palavra é: ' + args.sort(function(a, b){return b.length - a.length})[0]; 
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The", "quick", "brown"));
console.log(findLongestWord("Unknow", "quick", "brown"));
console.log(findLongestWord("Unknow", "quick", "brown_for_the_test"));
console.log(findLongestWord("The", "football", "brown"));
```

Não ser se sua ideia era passar um array como parâmetro, mas do jeito que você postou na pergunta, essa minha solução é possível que atenda o seu requisito.

Answer (score 3):

Se você quer passar as palavras como parâmetros para a função (como no seu exemplo: `findLongestWord("The", "quick", "brown")`), então uma opção é usar [*rest parameters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```js
function findLongestWord(...words) {
    var longest = "";
    for (var word of words) {
        if (word.length > longest.length) longest = word;
    }
    return longest;
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The", "quick", "brown")); // quick
```

Repare na declaração da função, que usei `...words` para indicar que a quantidade de parâmetros é variável, e todos eles serão colocados em `words`. No caso, `words` já será um array, e por isso não precisa usar `split` nem nada do tipo, basta percorrê-lo com `for`.

**E você também não precisa ordenar o array**: basta percorrê-lo e ir verificando o tamanho de cada string, para encontrar a maior. [A ordenação tem um custo O(n log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57763259), enquanto que percorrer o array em um `for` simples tem custo O(n). Ordenar o array me parece completamente desnecessário, já que você só quer pegar a maior string, e tanto faz as outras ([veja aqui](https://jsbench.me/1ekjxi6c8t/1) um comparativo e veja como ordenar o array faz com que seja mais lento).

No final, retorne a própria string, e não o tamanho dela (entendi que você quer a string, então não retorne o `length` e sim a própria string `longest`).

Vale lembrar que em caso de empate, a primeira string encontrada é retornada (no exemplo acima, tanto "quick" quanto "brown" são as maiores, e no caso, "quick" foi retornada por estar no array em uma posição anterior a "brown").

---

Em browsers mais antigos, não compatíveis com ES6, os *rest parameters* podem não estar disponíveis. Neste caso, outra alternativa é usar [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), que é um objeto *array-like* que contém todos os argumentos recebidos pela função:

```js
function findLongestWord(){
    var longest = "";
    for (var word of arguments) {
        if (word.length > longest.length) longest = word;
    }
    return longest;
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The", "quick", "brown")); // quick
```

---

#### Passando um array

Nos comentários foi dito que você quer passar um array com palavras para a função. Neste caso, precisaria de uma pequena modificação:

```js
function findLongestWord(words) { // words agora é um array
    var longest = "";
    for (var word of words) {
        if (word.length > longest.length) longest = word;
    }
    return longest;
}

console.log(findLongestWord([ "The", "quick", "brown" ])); // quick
```

Agora, ao chamar a função, eu passei `[ "The", "quick", "brown" ]` - repare nos colchetes, eles indicam que isso é um array (no caso, com 3 elementos: as strings `"The"`, `"quick"` e `"brown"`). Agora a função recebe um único parâmetro, que é o array contendo as palavras.

Isso é diferente de `findLongestWord("The", "quick", "brown")` <- neste caso, você está passando 3 parâmetros para a função (3 strings separadas), e não um array contendo as 3 strings.

Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas isso faz diferença caso o array esteja em uma variável. Veja:

```js
function recebeArray(words) {
    var longest = "";
    for (var word of words) {
        if (word.length > longest.length) longest = word;
    }
    return longest;
}

function recebeRestParams(...words) {
    var longest = "";
    for (var word of words) {
        if (word.length > longest.length) longest = word;
    }
    return longest;
}

// array com as palavras
let palavras = [ "The", "quick", "brown" ];

console.log(recebeArray(palavras)); // quick

console.log(recebeRestParams(palavras)); // não funciona
// para funcionar, precisa aplicar o spread operator no array
console.log(recebeRestParams(...palavras)); // quick
```

Para entender melhor sobre o *spread operator*, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111497/112052).