# Quando eu devo usar o "{ ...props }" no lugar de "props" no React?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou realizado alguns teste e algum lugar eu vi que estavam utilizando `{ ...props }` no parâmetro do componente.
Qual a diferença de usar `{ ...props }` de somente `props`?

```
export default function Botao(props) { ... }
export default function Botao({ ...props }) { ... }
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111497/112052

Comment: Não faz muito sentido utilizar parâmetros rest quando se trata de uma função que será utilizada para componentes do React, já que elas não são variádicas.

Comment: Você quis dizer `Botao({...props})`, certo?

Comment: @RafaelTavares isso mesmo, mas a minha dúvida foi respondida já. Obrigado

Comment: @ChristianViana caso a dúvida tenha sido sanada, aceita a resposta como "Melhor resposta".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No primeiro exemplo você recebe o objeto - contendo todos os atributos passados.

e.g.

```
export default function Button(props) { 
  return <button style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor}>{props.label}</button>
}

<Button backgroundColor="red" label="Click here" />
```

No segundo exemplo você pode usar `destructuring assignment` para "destruturar" os atributos desejados e posteriormente usamos o `spread operator` para atribuir os demais atributos a `props`.

e.g.

```
export default function Button({ label, backgroundColor, ...props }) {
  return <button style={{ backgroundColor }} {...props}>{label}</button>
}

<Button backgroundColor="red" label="Click here" onClick={() => alert("Pressed")} />
```

No exemplo acima, você destruturou os atributos `label` e `backgroundColor`, já os demais serão atribuídos a `props`; também podemos usar o `spread operator` para passar tudo que está em `props` para o elemento `button`.